# Reload UITableview data within MFSideMenuViewController from another viewcontroller

Tags: uitableview, mfslidemenu

I have use MFSideMenu but I am new with that. I have a UITableview in `MFSideMenuViewController`. Data in that `tableview` depend on the web service response.

When application start (`AppDelegate`) that `MFSideMenu` is set and related web service is called. With the response of the same, data is filled in the `tableview`. I have another view where I need to recall the webservice and refill the tableview data.

I have create object of the side menu containing class in the current (second) view and try to reload the data like below:

```
sideMenuContainingViewController *menu = [[sideMenuContainingViewController alloc] init];
[menu.tbl reloadData];
```

But with this the `numberOfRowsInSection` datasource of the table is called but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not called.

How to reload the table of MFSideMenu from another view?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43782634/3901620