# MF Side menu problems using dynamic Menu data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I have a problem because I want to put dynamic data in my side menu
I am using `[MFSideMenu]` with `Xcode Version 8.2.1` for `ios 10.2.1` and I have created a `SideMenuViewController : UITableViewController` where I design and populate data in my side menu.

When I start the app it shows all the data correctly. After login need to update the side menu data. i'm updating a menu array after login but table view showing the pervious data.

The only thing that makes the app show the correct data, is if I restart the app.

So my question what can be wrong, is it possible to use dynamic data in the side menu, and if so what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use NSNotificationCenter for refresh data.

1. Add in SideMenuViewController's ViewDidLoad

   ```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
           name:@"refreshData"
           object:nil];
   ```

2 . Add selector method in SideMenuViewController

```
 - (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
      [tableview reloadData];
}
```

3 . Now post notification while Login

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"refreshData" 
    object:self];
```